# Load balance on home wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, streaming

At my parents house (where I'm living for a few months) we have an ISP connection of 3 MBps down and 512 KBps up. On our network, we have a Roku box to stream videos from many sources, mostly Netflix. Whenever the Roku box is in use, the internet is almost useless. HTTP connections to web pages will go through after a couple tries. Is there anything I can do to mediate this issue?

My wireless router is the generic POS that came with the ATT service, a 2Wire 2701HG-B. This issue is also present when someone on a computer is streaming anything from anywhere, such as a youtube video.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use QOS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) to limit the bandwidth used by the Roku, or conversely, to reserve some bandwidth for web browsing traffic. I doubt your router can handle that. You might be able to reflash it with DD-WRT, but your best bet would be to look for a router that supports QOS out of the box.

Comment: Good answer, or upgrade your connection speed to your ISP. QOS is still a good investment anyway though.